# How do I run multiple background commands in bash in a single line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I normally run multiple commands with something like this:

```
sleep 2 && sleep 3
```

or

```
sleep 2 ; sleep 3
```

but what if I want to run them both in the background from one command line command?

```
sleep 2 & && sleep 3 &
```

doesn't work. And neither does replacing `&&` with `;`

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Use `()` to surround the command.

Answer (score 530, accepted):

Exactly how do you want them to run? If you want them to be started in the *background* and run **sequentially**, you would do something like this:

```
{ sleep 2; sleep 3; } &
```

If you want `sleep 3` to run only if `sleep 2` succeeds, then:

```
sleep 2 && sleep 3 &
```

If, on the other hand, you would like them to run in **parallel** in the *background*, you can instead do this:

```
sleep 2 & sleep 3 &
```

And the two techniques could be combined, such as:

```
{ sleep 2; echo first finished; } & { sleep 3; echo second finished; } &
```

Bash being bash, there's often a multitude of different techniques to accomplish the same task, although sometimes with subtle differences between them.

Comment: What happens if we do `sleep 2 && sleep 3 &` ? I tried it in bash and it seems to work the same way (tried with echo).

Comment: @HakanBaba, Yes it does indeed create a subshell in the background.

Comment: @Wajahat, Did you try `sleep 2 && echo "foo" && sleep 3 & echo "bar""` ? The `&&` operator tells the shell to execute the command before it, and only if that command executes without any error the shell executes the subsequent command. This is essentially different from `;`, because `;` lets the subsequent command execute regardless of the exit status of the previous command unless it was a fatal error. The `&` tells the shell to execute all of the "connected" commands preceding it, in the background. "connected" here means the command is part of a pipe ( `|` ) or a logical operator.

Comment: `Of these list operators, ‘&&’ and ‘||’ have equal precedence, followed by ‘;’ and ‘&’, which have equal precedence.` in bash manual.

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me - ```i=0;while [ $i -le 10 ]; do echo i:$i;i=$[$i+1];sleep 2;done; & j=10;while [ $j -ge 0 ]; do echo j:$j;j=$[$j-1];sleep 2;done; &``` or ```(i=0;while [ $i -le 10 ]; do echo i:$i;i=$[$i+1];sleep 2;done; &) ; (j=10;while [ $j -ge 0 ]; do echo j:$j;j=$[$j-1];sleep 2;done; &)``` gives out ```-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'``` error. Am i missing something?

Comment: This is not working. My first command runs `rdiff-backup` and I want to unmount the `source` when the command finishes. I put the command in backgrund like above, write to a logfile, and the next line in the script shows a log `tail -f logfile`. Now, if I cancel the `tail` it will also cancel the `rdiff-backup` which I put into background. I see this because the log will how a SIGTERM.

Answer (score 68):

You need to add some parens in your last version --

```
(sleep 2 &) && (sleep 3 &)
```

or this also works --

```
(sleep 2 &) ; (sleep 3 &)
```

Comment: Note : When a list is used with `&`, its exit status is always zero. So, the two cases above do the same thing(The shell executes both sides in turn *asynchronously*).

Answer (score 11):

to run multiple background command you need to add `&` end of each command.
ex:
`(command1 &) && (command2 &) && (command3 &)`

Comment: -1. Joining bg'ed commands with `&&` accomplishes nothing, since they always return zero immediately. That is, it's the same as using `;`. What OP wants is `(command 1 && command 2) &`

Answer (score 7):

The answers above use parentheses.  Bash also can use braces for a similar purpose:

```
{ sleep 2 && sleep 3; } &
```

Note that the braces are more picky about syntax--the space after `{`, the space before `}`, and the final semicolon are required.  In some situations the braces are more efficient because they don't fork a new subshell.  In this case I don't know if it makes a difference.

Comment: What about `{ sleep 2; sleep 3; } &`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the bash command substitution `$(command)` like this:

```
$(command1 ; command2) &
```

Note that stdin and stdout are still linked to the parent process and redirecting at least the stdout can be tricky. So alternatively you can chain the commands in a single line then pass the string to the `bash` command to spawn a new process which will handle the execution.

```
bash -c "command1 ; command2" &
```

This is especially useful in a bash script when you need to run multiple commands in background.

These two statements should be equivalent. A **bash** process is spawn in both cases to handle the command (chain of commands) and the `&` at the end detaches the execution.

This time you can add `&>/dev/null` before the `&` at the end of the command to redirect at least the stdout and avoid the output on the stdout of the parent process. Something like:

```
bash -c "command1 ; command2" &>/dev/null &
```

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
$(sleep 2 &) && sleep 3 &
```

Also you can do:

```
$(sleep 2 && sleep 3) &
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same mission too.
I have try `(sleep2 ; fg )& sleep3 ; fg`,it's working.
And when you preass ctrl+c doubled,the two process can be stoppped.