# Precedence of operators in Bash

Tags: bash, operators

I have an expression `cat file.txt | script.sh 1> output.txt || mkdir TEST &`. Does `&` at the end mean that only `mkdir` executes in the background or the whole expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the `&`, it will affect the whole expression.
You can easily check it with something not as elegant as simple like:

```
echo '1' > file1  || echo '2' > file2 &
```

(to put some output redirection as you have), otherwise, just

```
echo '1' || echo '2' &
```

Here the output of the first echo will return true and the second part in the condition won't be executed, but it will go to the background anyways.

and then, you can check:

```
false || echo '2' > file2  &
```

or the easier version:

```
false || echo '2' &
```

Here, the echo will be executed, and also in background.

Then, in both cases it will be executed in background, even if in the first case only the first part is executed and in the second only se second part is executed.

Comment: Is there any difference between `(cat file.txt | script.sh 1> output.txt || mkdir TEST) &` and `cat file.txt | script.sh 1> output.txt || mkdir TEST &`?

Comment: No, they will execute the same.

Answer (score 2):

`&` and `;` are separators in the POSIX shell language. They apply to whole pipelines.

You can either devise an experiment to (dis)prove it:

```
[ ! -d TEST ] || rmdir TEST #cleanup
sleep 1 | (sleep 1 ; false) || mkdir TEST & 
ls -d TEST #will run immediately (because & applied to the whole pipeline) 
#but fail because the `||` part wasn't reached yet
```

Or you can look it up in the POSIX specification for the [shell grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_10).

Answer (score 1):

If you put the `&` at the end of the command it will run the whole command in the background. You can do some thing like this to run it in parallel in background

```
(cat file.txt | grep e > output.txt) & (mkdir TEST) &
```

This answer may make it clear: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612371/how-do-i-run-multiple-background-commands-in-bash-in-a-single-line)