# Chain 2 backgrounded bash commands on 1 Heroku Dyno using Procfile

Tags: bash, heroku, procfile

[This Heroku Help page](https://help.heroku.com/CTFS2TJK/how-do-i-run-multiple-processes-on-a-dyno) suggests I can run multiple commands backgrounded, followed by `wait -n`, in my `Procfile`. Their example:

```
web: puma -C config/puma.rb & sidekiq & wait -n
```

In my example, the commands I want to run are in different directories, so I wrote:

```
web: cd api/ && bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb & cd .. && sh target/bin/worker & wait -n
```

#### Problem

My heroku app crashes. `heroku logs` shows:

```
2020-04-26T22:50:37.104343+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 0: Can't open target/bin/worker
2020-04-26T22:50:55.157670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

But if I do `heroku run bash` and then `sh target/bin/worker`, it runs fine. And all the files are where I expect:

```
$ heroku run bash
Running bash on [redacted]... up, run.[redacted] (Free)
~ $ ls -al api/config/puma.rb
-rw------- 1 u37764 dyno 1579 Apr 26 22:43 api/config/puma.rb
~ $ ls -al target/bin/worker
-rw------- 1 u37764 dyno 11952 Apr 26 22:45 target/bin/worker
```

So I think something may be incorrect with the way I'm chaining commands (e.g. mixing `&&` and `&`). I saw [this related bash question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14612371/1445366) but still couldn't figure out the correct syntax.

What is it?

> #### I also tried…
>
> - `puma` needs to be run from inside the `api/` directory, so e.g. `web: puma -C api/config/puma.rb & sh target/bin/worker & wait -n` doesn't work either.)
> - `web: sh start.sh` where `start.sh` contains:
>
>   ```sh
>   #!/usr/bin/env sh
>   cd api/
>   bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb &
>   cd ..
>   sh target/bin/worker &
>   wait -n
>   ```

Comment: `wait -n` is a bash feature not sh afaik.

Comment: Go into Linux and run `cd /tmp` followed by a `cd ~/Desktop && pwd & cd .. && pwd`. Observation: `/` and `/home/yourusername/Desktop` is printed. You expected `/home/yourusername` to be printed. This assumption was wrong.