# How to run two applications (deamon and client) at the same time in single SSH using Python Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I want to run client and daemon application which responds to client in the same time.

Connection established to SSH using Paramiko. But I could not run both daemon and client in the same time.

How to do this with Paramiko?

Here the expectation is, client provide input as 1,2,3 and daemon responds to each input.
Both run in the same SSH.

Could any one help me with this?

Comment: Have you thought of having 2 separate `paramiko` sessions in 2 separate threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you can use simple shell syntax to achieve what you need. You do not need any fancy code in Python/Paramiko.

Assuming *nix server, see [How do I run multiple background commands in bash in a single line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14612371/850848)

To run (any) command in Paramiko, see [Execute command and wait for it to finish with Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34181078/850848)

So probably like this:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command("deamon & client")
stdout.channel.set_combine_stderr(True)
output = stdout.readlines()
```

---

If you need to somehow run the two commands (deamon and clinet) independenty for a better control, you can start here:
[Run multiple commands in different SSH servers in parallel using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66191219/850848)

Except that you do not need to open multiple connections (`SSHClient`). You will just call `SSHClient.exec_command` twice on the same `SSHClient` instance.